# why vue props decoding JSON strigifyed object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, stringify, vue-props

I am passing a stringifyed object via props to a component like below.

```
<my-component :filter="stringobject" ></my-component>
```

```
stringobject = "{"search_text":"(ciClass like '%5684%') AND status NOT IN ('Terminated','Closed','Implemented')"}"
```

Inside "my-component"  when I receive the filter prop, the query is being changed to
**ciClass like 'v84%'**

Somehow vue is converting the '%56' to 'v'. In my-component the type of the prop is String.

I tried to escape it with backslash, storing the string in variable first, tried using encoded chars instead of quotes but it didn't work. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In my stringifyed object, I repalced % with %25 and it started working! I am not very sure how and why this decoding was taking place.